# List all files of one type in android

Tags: java, android, file

I need to retrieve a list of all files of a certain type on my internal and external storage. I found this (-> [List all of one file type on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298858/list-all-of-one-file-type-on-android-device)) example, but it's very mp3 specific.

My app creates a .zip file which is renamed to the extension *.message

Another activity should display a list of all available .message files, from which the user can choose one to open it.

Does anyone has an idea how to begin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain a list of files with a specific extension you can use `File.list()` with a `FilenameFilter`. For example:

```
File dir = new File(".");

String[] names = dir.list(
    new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return name.endsWith(".message");
        }
    });
```

Note that the returned strings are file names only, they do not contain the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
File root = new File(globalVar.recordDir);

{
    try {
        if (root.listFiles().length > 0) {
            for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    //DO somthings with it
                } 
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly does globalVar.recordDir mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry. it 's my directory. Ex : /sdcard/recordDrir/