# How to play a ringtone which is only for Push Notification Arrivals of my application?

Tags: android, push-notification, ringtone

I am working on Android, and I have implemented Push Notifications feature in my app using GCM.

And my intention is to play a ringtone from app Assets or device Sdcard when only for my Application related push Notification arrivals in the installed device.

Comment: take a look at this:: [Setting Ringtone notification from SD card file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029876/setting-ringtone-notification-from-sd-card-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create 1 folder named raw under yourApp/res/

2.Do copy and paste your ringtone in this folder

3.Write the below code when your application notify the notification.!

```
            SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

            int iTmp = sp.load(context, R.raw.windows_8_notify, 1); // in 2nd param u have to pass your desire ringtone

            sp.play(iTmp, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.windows_8_notify); // in 2nd param u have to pass your desire ringtone
            //mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thank you.And Does it works with push notifications. because notifications are going to sends by the server side .

Comment: @Ganesh-Yes it will work when you are going to send from server..Have you tried it?

Comment: My Intentions is to play music file from sdcard. and I would like to download the music file from server to sdcard or ExternalCacheDirectory when application installs in device .

Comment: @Ganesh-Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005566/how-to-play-mp3-files-from-internal-and-external-sd-card-in-android also http://easyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/09/media-player-example-in-android-howto.html